# Print error in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have text file like this:

```
tw004:Galaxy S5:Samsung:Mobilni telefon:7
tw002:Galaxy S6:Samsung:Mobilni telefon:7
tw001:Huawei P8:Huawei:Mobilni telefon:3
tw003:Huawei P9:Huawei:Mobilni telefon:9
```

(where tw001 to tw004 is code of some devices and last part of a line is amount 7,7,3,9)

And code like this:

```
def export_devices():
        code = input("Enter device code: ")
        amount = int(input("How many devices you export: "))
        with open("uredjaji.txt", "r+") as f:
            current_position = 0
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                if line[:len(code) + 1] == code + ":":
                    remaining_content = f.read()
                    f.seek(current_position)
                    f.truncate()
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    amount_index = line.rfind(":") - 1
                    current_amount = int(line[amount_index:])
                    line = line[:amount_index] + str(current_amount + amount) + "\n"
                    f.write(line)
                    f.write(remaining_content)
                    return
                current_position = f.tell()
                line = f.readline()
        print("Invalid device code: {}".format(code))

export_devices()
```

Now I want to print error if **input amount** is bigger then **current amount** in file. This is not quite my code, so I can't soulution but I tried on so many ways with some IF statments, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that code looks familiar... Anyway, just move the `current_amount` parsing before destructive changes to the file and add a check after you parse it:

```
def export_devices():
        code = input("Enter device code: ")
        amount = int(input("How many devices you export: "))
        with open("uredjaji.txt", "r+") as f:
            current_position = 0
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                if line[:len(code) + 1] == code + ":":
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    amount_index = line.rfind(":") + 1
                    current_amount = int(line[amount_index:])
                    if amount > current_amount:
                        print("Input amount larger than the current amount...")
                        return
                    remaining_content = f.read()
                    f.seek(current_position)
                    f.truncate()
                    line = line[:amount_index] + str(current_amount + amount) + "\n"
                    f.write(line)
                    f.write(remaining_content)
                    return
                current_position = f.tell()
                line = f.readline()
        print("Invalid device code: {}".format(code))

export_devices()
```

You should also try to understand the code you're using. I wrote the extensive comments in my answer to your previous question so you can understand what it does, and if something is not clear you should ask about it rather than just blindly copy-pasting the code.

Comment: Thank's for help, bro. But now, I have error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n:9'

In line:
current_amount = int(line[amount_index:])

I'm sorry if I am boring, but I'm preatty much new here. I will no more ask you a million questions :)

Comment: @КонстантиновићГоран - that's because you mis-copied the original code (presumably to clean out the comments, but why?) and added a `-` instead of a `+` when finding the `amount_index`, check the update above.